# Using multiple frame in a wpf window

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm developing an application using WPF by c#.

I have 2 frames next to each other. The above will not change and just updated(like Facebook toolbar).

The bottom frame will change by clicking on some buttons. (it is something like masterpage in ASP).

I don't want to set a height and width for window or for frames. The problem is when I make the window full screen there is a space between two frames.

However none of the vertical/horizontal alignment stretch does not work.

```
    <window>
    <Frame    VerticalAlignment="Top"  Background="Crimson" />
        <Frame   VerticalAlignment="Bottom"  Background="Black" 
/>
</Window>
```

I want to create something like the this site as you see. the notify section and the main page.
EDIT:

i can put them next to each other just by set the height, but when i make full the window the heights stay and the yellow space becomes appear, so i want to find a way to put them Exactly next to each other in every window size.

Comment: Look at `DockPanel` or `Grid` with row heights of `Auto, *`.

Comment: Please show the shortest code to reproduce the issue you have, along with how you would like it to work, that will make it easier to help you.

Answer (score 0):

As Mitch noted in the comments, you could place the two frames in a grid instead, and let the grid size the items.

```
<Window>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Frame Grid.Row="0" Background="Crimson" />
        <Frame Grid.Row="1" Background="Black" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: unfortunately it does not work for me.it is still shows the window only. did you test it? don't you have any idea to create something like masterpage in my application??

Comment: "It still shows the window only"? In your OP you did not state this. What is your actual problem then, because this should work based on the information in your question?

Comment: i can put them next to each other just by set the height, but when i make full the window the heights stay and the yellow space becomes appear, so i want to find a way to put them Exactly next to each other in every window size.

Comment: But using the solution above, the top frame will have one size, and the bottom frame will occupy all of the other space. If this does not work for you, then you have some other problem that makes the sizes incorrect.

Comment: exactly i want that you say, the other has to occupy other space, but does not work!!!! Anyway, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Grid>
   <Grid.RowDefinitions>
         <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
         <RowDefinition Height="*"/>

   </Grid.RowDefinitions>

   <Frame Grid.Row="0" Background="Crimson" />
    <Frame Grid.Row="1" Background="Black" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: This will size the two frames equally, which is not what the OP wanted.

Comment: can you explain more what do you want.

Comment: Now you've just copied my answer exactly. What does this answer add that my answer did not cover?

Comment: when I wrote the first version of my answer it was different from your answer, after the the first comment I noticed that, and I modified my answer. but really I did not noticed that it is exactly the same to your answer after i did the modification on it.

Comment: I just want to say that I did not copied you answer at all, it is just a coincident,  and I will delete it if you want.